# Is there an R package to check the proportional odds assumpion?

Tags: r, logistic, ordinal-data, polr

is there an R package/function to implement the parallel slope test given a clm (ordinal package) or polr (MASS) package?

Answer (score 1):

I use the VGAM-package to fit proportional odds models / or to test for these...